# How attach <%= %> and login form (devise) in vue components

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

I have vue component

```
Vue.component('my-modal', {
template: '<div class="modal-open "> <div class="modal-dialog" role="document"> <div class="modal-content"> <div class="modal-header"> <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5> <button type="button" class="close material-icons" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" @click="$emit(\'close\')" ><a class="material-icons" style="color: black">cancel</a></button></div> <div class="modal-body"> <p><%= User.find(1).name %></p> </div> <div class="modal-footer"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" @click="$emit(\'close\')">Close</button> </div> </div> </div> </div>'
})

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data: {
        showLoginModal: false
    },
});
});
```

It is modal windows. I want to render login form in modal window, but it`s in vue component

In the component, i use (for example)

```
<%= User.find(1).name %>
```

but it does not work, displays as text. How integrate rails heplers or login form in vue components???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

If you want to pass your data into vue component, you can use `props`:

```
# rails view
<my-modal name="<%= User.find(1).name %>"></my-modal>


# vue component
Vue.component('my-modal', {
  template: `<div class="modal-open ">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>{{ name }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>`,
  props: ['name']
})
```

If you want to display rails form into vue component, you can use `slot`:

```
# rails view
<my-modal>
  <%= form_for @whatever do |f| %>
    ...
  <% end %>
</my-modal>


# vue component
Vue.component('my-modal', {
  template: `<div class="modal-open ">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <slot />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>`
})
```